# How to change the access rights for a file in linux

Tags: linux

I would like to change the permission for a script in Linux. 
I have managed to give it permissions for all groups/users with the following command:
chmod 700 script.sh and now it looks like drwxrwxrwt

What I'd like to know is what is the value for: -rwxr-xr-x and what is the actual logic behind the process.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If it starts with d, it's a directory and not a file. The other nine letters come in groups of three, for the user, groups, and everyone. Each of them works as a bitfield, so 4 + 2 + 1 would give you 7, meaning user, group, and everyone else can read, write, and xecute. If you wanted only read and write for that group it would be 4 + 2 + 0 for that user/group/other.

So if you wanted user to be rwx, group to be rw- and others to be just r, it would be 764.

Answer (score -1):

value 0 means "No Permission" and symbol= ---
value 1 means "execute" and symbol= --x
value 2 means "Write" and symbol= -w-
value 3 means "execute + write" and symbol= -wx
value 4 means "read" and symbol= r--
value 5 means "read + execute" and symbol= r-x
value 6 means "read + write" and symbol= rw-
value 7 means "read + write + execute" and symbol= rwx

So value for " -rwxr-xr-x" is 755
i.e execute command: chmod 755 file_name